# How do I change a background color in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the background color of a div(dashboard) from JS. As of now it only changes for a second and resets back to the original color.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var divtag = document.getElementById("dashboard");
  divtag.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard">
  <i class="fas fa-compact-disc fa-5x"></i>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Track Search</legend>
      <input type="text" id="tname" name="tname" placeholder="Specify a Track">
      <button class="far fa-file-audio fa-2x" onclick="searchT()"></button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form name="color" onsubmit="validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Music Dashboard Scheme</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="RGB" name="choice" value="RGB" checked="checked">
      <label for="RGB">RGB</label>
      <input type="radio" id="HEX" name="choice" value="HEX">
      <label for="HEX">HEX</label>
      <input type="text" id="cvalue" name="cvalue" placeholder="Enter Colour Value" required>
      <input type="submit" src="fas fa-palette fa-2x" alt="Submit"></input>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you submit your form and the page reloads, losing any change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preventDefault` to disable default submitting behaviour.

Like that:

```js
function validateForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var divtag = document.getElementById("dashboard");
  divtag.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the form submit reloads the page. You could avoid it by passing `event` to `validateForm`, and calling [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) inside the function.

```js
function validateForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var divtag = document.getElementById("dashboard");
  divtag.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard">
  <i class="fas fa-compact-disc fa-5x"></i>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Track Search</legend>
      <input type="text" id="tname" name="tname" placeholder="Specify a Track">
      <button class="far fa-file-audio fa-2x" onclick="searchT()"></button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form name="color" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Music Dashboard Scheme</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="RGB" name="choice" value="RGB" checked="checked">
      <label for="RGB">RGB</label>
      <input type="radio" id="HEX" name="choice" value="HEX">
      <label for="HEX">HEX</label>
      <input type="text" id="cvalue" name="cvalue" placeholder="Enter Colour Value" required>
      <input type="submit" src="fas fa-palette fa-2x" alt="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` the function in your `onsubmit` event handler, then within your function, return `false`. This tells the browser not to submit your form.

```js
function validateForm() {

  var divtag = document.getElementById("dashboard");
  divtag.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  
  return false
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard">
  <i class="fas fa-compact-disc fa-5x"></i>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Track Search</legend>
      <input type="text" id="tname" name="tname" placeholder="Specify a Track">
      <button class="far fa-file-audio fa-2x" onclick="searchT()"></button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <form name="color" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Music Dashboard Scheme</legend>
      <input type="radio" id="RGB" name="choice" value="RGB" checked="checked">
      <label for="RGB">RGB</label>
      <input type="radio" id="HEX" name="choice" value="HEX">
      <label for="HEX">HEX</label>
      <input type="text" id="cvalue" name="cvalue" placeholder="Enter Colour Value" >
      <input type="submit" src="fas fa-palette fa-2x" alt="Submit"   />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```